# Webserver virtual network

Tags: javascript, networking, social-networking

It's quite hard for me to figure out if this sort of thing has ever been implemented. I want to look for any libraries that may exist so I don't go about reinventing the wheel.

I have this idea of having a web app that connects the people who are on the site. Every user that is connected to the site may communicate to another user also on the site via the server. So the protocols will be implemented in JavaScript, and the server simply helps to identify users, and just echoes data to enable the communication. For instance I can use this to implement my game networking ideas in javascript, and easily test them without having my testers download any executables, they can just log onto the site.

Now obviously this isn't going to be an effective architecture for any kind of serious application. But I think if I can get it working I could build really cool networking apps without having any sort of download.

What I'm thinking about is using ajax for client->webserver and webserver->client (Comet?) and I can code up the webserver echo bit with PHP or a cgi script. And then I can implement an entirely separate protocol in JS that the webserver does not care or know about.

The reason for having the webserver echo everything is because I don't want to use java or anything else that I can open up sockets in. Why make it harder for me? Because I can and because I happen to be really enamored with javascript at the moment. It's the only web technology I trust. Screw java applets.

Does this make any sense to anyone? Am I crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about the crazy part ([there's a proposal at area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14303/psychology-and-psychiatry), go check that) but it's definitely doable.

- You could use a plain old XMPP server and a javascript XMPP client (there are libraries - for example strophe)
- You could do it with AJAX and a PHP backend: [Making an AJAX Web Chat](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/)
- You could use the fancy Websockets from HTML5: [Start Using HTML5 WebSockets](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/)
- You could use some existing component if you can find any (I couldn't find any *I* would use)

Cheers :)